# Loading my transparent activity hides the keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity

I manage some events in a background BroadcastReceiver. In some specific situations I need to launch an activity. This activity is supposed to be hidden. Nothing should be displayed to the user.

It works well but if the user is using the keyboard, typing something, the keyboard is hidden. If the user is using GMail, writing an email, then a "draft" is saved.

It seems like this activity gets to the top and stops the one the user is using even if it is invisible. Is there any way to solve this?

This how I declare the activity in manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MyInvisbleActivity" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

This is how I launch it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyContext, MyInvisbleActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MyContext.startActivity(intent);
```

This is the MyInvisbleActivity onCreate():

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                

    //setContentView(---); //This is not used          
    Window oWindow = getWindow();
    oWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

    --do work--
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: "This activity is supposed to be hidden" -- why?

Comment: For example, if I get a LowBattery event I want to disconnect bluetooth. If the user is typing I don't want to hide the keyboard

Comment: Why do you need an activity to disconnect bluetooth?

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Android provides a theme for this `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

Alternatively it sounds like you might actually want a service. But youd need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I also added oWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

Comment: @Ton I don't understand why you've unaccepted my answer a week after accepting it and indicating it fixed your problem?

Comment: Sorry Nick. I found out the problem is back. My users reported a false fix. So I am still trying to find the solution to load a transparent activity without hidding the keyboard.

Comment: Ok, I think this still solves your issue though - you need to implement a service, that way the intent can be handled in the background and shouldn't interrupt your user. It probably differs slightly across android versions but whether visible or not, a new activity still takes focus from the user and thus hides the keyboard